# Make part of Text From InputBox not Editable in Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How do i Make a part of Text Not Editable ..

My .html code is

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name" class="wc-form-control nobg" formControlName="subject" " id="subjectid">
```

My .ts code is to append the Input box with class

```
var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = ('<span class="nonEdit"> {{' + this.checboxvalue + '}} </span>');
        this.editecompanydetail.patchValue({subject: this.editecompanydetail.value.subject + el.innerHTML })
```

But it is getting appended with  tag , Any solution on this ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `contenteditable="false"` like this:

```
var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = ('<span class="nonEdit" contenteditable="false"> {{' + this.checboxvalue + '}} </span>');
        this.editecompanydetail.patchValue({subject: this.editecompanydetail.value.subject + el.innerHTML })
```

You could also try with `readonly`:

```
var el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = ('<span class="nonEdit" readonly> {{' + this.checboxvalue + '}} </span>');
        this.editecompanydetail.patchValue({subject: this.editecompanydetail.value.subject + el.innerHTML })
```

hope it helps :)

Similar cases:

- [How can I make a span tag un-deletable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373506/how-can-i-make-a-span-tag-un-deletable)
- [How do I make a text input non-editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676127/how-do-i-make-a-text-input-non-editable/3676132)

More on the topic:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `[disabled] = true` to make the field non editable to your input tag.